# JSONEncoder doesnt work integer values below IOS 13-

Tags: ios, json, swift, encoding

I'm trying to send a Integer value to WebService with body so I created a function like that :

```
 static func GetRoomVersionAndRemainingSeconds(auctionId:Int,completed:@escaping (ServiceResultDene<String>)->()){
    var memberJson : String = ""
    do{
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(auctionId)
        memberJson = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    
        
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: WebServiceUrls.GetRoomVersionAndRemainingSeconds)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue(Util.cookie, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
    request.httpBody = (memberJson).data(using: .unicode)
    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON{response in 
     .... 
     }
```

When I try above code , it perfectly  encode the Integer value on `IOS 13+` -- `memberJson is = "\"4\""`
But when I try this on `IOS 12.4` It doesnt encode and `error.localizedDescription` returns : `invalidValue(4, Swift.EncodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Top-level Int encoded as number JSON fragment.", underlyingError: nil))`
What is the problem is here ? Any suggestion could be good.Thanks

Comment: Don't print `error.localizedDescription`, print `error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON encoding is pointless. In practice you are going to convert an `Int` to a `String`.

This can be done much simpler

```
static func GetRoomVersionAndRemainingSeconds(auctionId: Int,completed: @escaping (ServiceResultDene<String>)->()){

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: WebServiceUrls.GetRoomVersionAndRemainingSeconds)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue(Util.cookie, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
    request.httpBody = Data(String(auctionId).utf8)
    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON{response in 
      .... 
    }
```

By the way the reason of the error is that `JSONEncoder` doesn’t support to encode fragments prior to iOS 13.

Comment: Thanks. JSONEncoder works when you encode Model Below IOS 13.0 but yeah when I try to encode Int like I did , It doesnt work.